# What justification is there to flag this question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support

What justification is there to flag [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33944/what-is-biblical-basis-for-the-lutheran-church-of-sweden-for-performing-full-sam) question as a duplicate?

The question flagged was the one which was asked first and not the other that is being said it is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 6):

The "SE definition" of duplicate is that a question (call it Q2) is considered a duplicate of another question (Q1) if the answers to Q1 also answer Q2.  I know this isn't the situation you're asking about, but this sometimes trips people up e.g. when they are asking a fairly limited question and there is already a broader question and some answers.

It's *my impression* (I don't know if it's SE policy and I can't be bothered to go looking right now) that it's ok to mark an older question as a duplicate of a newer question if the newer one has better answers.  I'm pretty sure I've seen this happen even with a months-older question being marked as a duplicate of a newer one, and it *could* make sense.  Again, using my example of a limited vs. a broad question, someone could ask a more general question later.

It's also *my impression* that SE recently changed policy and doesn't allow a question Q2 to be closed as a duplicate of Q1 if Q1 has no answers at all or even no upvoted answers.  This sort-of makes sense - how can you close something as a duplicate if there are no answers to judge?  I'm pretty sure I've seen this sort of duplicate before, but recently on ServerFault marking something as a duplicate wasn't allowed because there were no upvoted answers.

OTOH, you can certainly imagine cases where it's obvious even w/out any answers to either Q1 or Q2 that they are duplicates.

So for your recent string of 3 questions, the fact that an older one was marked as duplicate of a newer one seems to be fine as far as SE policy goes, but I think current SE policy wouldn't allow them to be closed as duplicates because there are no answers yet.

On the gripping hand, I look at those 3 recent questions and it sure seems to me that the answers would be very very similar...

Comment: Ward is right.  It is legitimate to close older questions as a duplicate of a new one.  See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha)

Comment: @DavidStratton I cannot think of an objective, non-arbitrary reason why it would not be. It's not something I've ever been troubled with. I always mark the lesser question as the duplicate. The one that is just not as well written.